# Initial HTTP request: index or routing?

Tags: asp.net, http

When we send an HTTP request to a web server as to load a web page e.g. http://wwww.nothing_is_here.com, what exactly the server does as to serve our request? Till now, I thought the server was looking to find a file named `index` (*index.html, index.php*) which should have HTML content and send it back to our browser. Now, I know this is not always the case. For example, in ASP .NET where we apply routing, `home/index` path is added to the URL by default as for our app to be routed. **That's I cannot understand is how exactly the server acts upon a similar situation**. *Why it does not return an error message in case there is no index file, how it knows it has to apply routing rules*? `How can we instruct the server what to do in either case`?

Answer (score 0):

What the server does when it receives a request for the root (which is what it will receive in your example), is up to the server configuration.  It is not within the control of the client making the request.

The server will be configured to have a default document (file name) in such cases, which is often index.html, but equally could be any file set by the administrator of the server.

The server will often be configured to recognise different hosts (e.g. if it's serving multiple sites on the same interface:port.  These different sites will often have different configuration about what the default file name(s) is/are (if any).  In some cases the server is configured to display a directory listing of a server-configured site root folder.